# How to change the alpha of an uneditable LineEdit to 1?

Tags: text, godot, alpha

I noticed that Godot changes the alpha of the LineEdit text when editable = false. I want the alpha to stay 1.
What I'm trying to do here is let the user input a name and then when they press enter it saves it in some dict etc (not important) and still shows as normal text (they can't edit it again)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [the LineEdit text's alpha appears to be hardcoded to 0.5 when it's disabled](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/e043bad230ab7e3869605a2da6638e2cb703c58b/scene/gui/line_edit.cpp#L647-L652). I guess it could be replaced with a custom color property instead – this should be an easy addition, but it will require modifying the engine's source code.